# Comparing table.Cell to a string failing in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, ms-word

I'm pretty new to python (using 2.7) and I'm trying to read contents of a specific table in an MS word file. I'm using `win32com.client` for this.

For finding my required table, I'm trying to compare `if table.Cell(1,2) == "Known string"`. So if this gives `True`, I can just focus on this table and manipulate it further. But this condition always seems to fail even when I'm running the code over all the tables. And I know for sure that at least one table should have this matched.

when I do `print table.Cell(1,2)`, I can see `"Known string"` as the output. But the comparison just doesn't seem to work. Tried adding `.Range.Text` as well with no luck.

I've added portion of my script below.

```
while table_n <= table_count:
    table = doc.Tables(table_n)
    col_count = table.Columns.Count
    print "This is %dth table and it has %d columns" % (table_n,col_count)
    if col_count == 4:
        content = table.Cell(1,2).Range.Text
        print "Content of table(1,2) = %s" % content
        if content == "Known content":
            print "true that"
    table_n += 1
```

Comment: To add some more details which I found later on. I tried `print "Content of table(1,2) = %r" % content` (Used `%r`). And this time the content was printed as `u 'Known Content\r\x07`. I think may be some formatting or encoding is still present with the content which is why the comparison might be failing. Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you try to compare just the first few characters (to see if it is just the \r\x07 part)

Answer (score 0):

In this documentation http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html

They do

```
 Cell(1,2).Value
```

Can you try it?

Comment: Tried your suggestion but it returns `AttributeError`